# npm --version failing inside podman container

Tags: node.js, podman

This could be a potential podman issue.

When trying to execute the following `podman run -it --rm node:lts npm --version` it kind of core dumps.

```
# podman run -it --rm node:lts npm --version
node[1]: ../src/node_platform.cc:68:std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start(): Assertion `(0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))' failed.
 1: 0xb87bc0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xb87c3e  [node]
 3: 0xbf50fe  [node]
 4: 0xbf51e1 node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*, v8::PageAllocator*) [node]
 5: 0xb458f3 node::InitializeOncePerProcess(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, node::ProcessFlags::Flags) [node]
 6: 0xb45f4b node::Start(int, char**) [node]
 7: 0x7f860c4f51ca  [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 8: 0x7f860c4f5285 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 9: 0xac3f4e _start [node]
```

Any workaround for this issue?

Here is the `podman info` output if it helps:

```
host:
  BuildahVersion: 1.11.7
  CgroupVersion: v1
  Conmon:
    package: conmon-2.0.8-1.el7.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.8, commit: f85c8b1ce77b73bcd48b2d802396321217008762'
  Distribution:
    distribution: '"centos"'
    version: "7"
  MemFree: 480374784
  MemTotal: 1929195520
  OCIRuntime:
    name: runc
    package: runc-1.0.0-69.rc10.el7_9.x86_64
    path: /usr/bin/runc
    version: 'runc version spec: 1.0.1-dev'
  SwapFree: 1073737728
  SwapTotal: 1073737728
  arch: amd64
  cpus: 2
  eventlogger: journald
  hostname: pm20231010
  kernel: 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64
  os: linux
  rootless: false
  uptime: 1h 13m 42.4s (Approximately 0.04 days)
registries:
  blocked: null
  insecure: null
  search:
  - registry.access.redhat.com
  - registry.redhat.io
  - docker.io
store:
  ConfigFile: /etc/containers/storage.conf
  ContainerStore:
    number: 0
  GraphDriverName: overlay
  GraphOptions: {}
  GraphRoot: /var/lib/containers/storage
  GraphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  ImageStore:
    number: 1
  RunRoot: /var/run/containers/storage
  VolumePath: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes
```